# Complex integral of exponential and power

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Let $n$ be an integer. Compute $$\int_{|z|=1}e^zz^{-n}dz.$$

If I parametrize $z(t)=e^{it}$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$, this becomes $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}e^{-nit}ie^{it}dt = i\int e^{e^{it}-(n-1)it} dt$$ and this looks too complicated.

Also I thought about using Cauchy's formula, but the function $e^zz^{-(n-1)}$ might not even be defined at $z=0$.

How can I find this integral?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives? (Hint: differentiate the Cauchy integral formula)

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? Notice
$f$ is holomorphic on $B_1(0) \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Do I have to worry about the case where $n<0$? Would it need to be handled differently?

Comment: The case $n \leqslant 0$ is different. Then the integrand is an entire function, and by the Cauchy integral theorem, the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cauchy Integral formula tells you that the integral is 
$$ f^{n-1}(0) = \frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^n}dz$$
from which you get $\displaystyle \frac{2 \pi i}{(n-1)!}$

The other way as AlexR mentioned in comment, we look for the residue of the integrand in the domain $|z| \le 1$.

$$z^{-n} e^z  = z^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k}}{k!}$$
The residue is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ which is coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Do I have to worry about the case where $n<0$? Would it need to be handled differently?

Comment: Well, if $\;n<0\;$ then the function is analytic everywhere and thus the integral over any closed , simple path is zero...

Answer (score 4):

By Cauchy's Integral Theorem:

$$\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^n}=\left.\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\left(e^z\right)^{(n-1)}\right|_{z=0}=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}$$